# Swift Facebook Login AppID Not Registered as a URL Scheme

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, info.plist, app-id

I'm getting the following error when trying to login with Facebook

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'fb---AppID--- is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist'**

The problem is the "fb---AppID---" is in my Info.plist file. I followed the 3 bullet points listed in the FB Documentation shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/1631628883742199/?platform=ios).

I copied the app name and app id directly from the documentation. What am I doing wrong? Is there a step missing in the documentation? Did I not configure it correctly somewhere else?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Do not copy and paste the App Name given to you on step 2 of the section titled "Configure your info.plist" on the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/1631628883742199/?platform=ios).

I assumed it was the name of my ios project, but it's actually the App Name in your bundle identifier. The only difference between the two was that the first character of the app name in my bundle identifier was not capitalized.

Answer (score 3):

Another issue with that may be if you already integrated another login service like Google for ex, and you already have the "URL types" and "URL Schemas" in your info.plist

Make sure you looked the entire info.plist and not duplicating those nodes, just ad your Facebook data to the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by consulting the facebook documentation where I saw that  had the fb prefix before the ID of the app, and FacebookAppID didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "fb" prefix from the FacebookAppID (Only from FacebookAppID)

Answer (score 0):

Even after all changes  suggestion the error message  happened, than after a long time working on one suffixed was created at developer.facebook.com on iOS place and on info.plist the same code was inserted on FacebookUrlSuffix string, finally the message erros disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem inserting

`ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)`

in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions